# How to change allowed attachment files extensions

Tags: themes

I have general question to group of WP themes that allow creating a classified ad websites.

I would like to know which file/part of code/function is responsible for restriction of attachments. These themes allows only images to be attached to the posted ad.

My aim is to expand allowed files format adding the 3d-model files (like .stl, .obj) that cant be execute on the server site and cannnot harm the server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're going to need to ask their authors. They probably all do it in a different way.

Comment: I have talked to one developer and he said that this group of themes have very similar function structure. I'm just new to Wordpress as well as i am very beginner at modifying code so i would like someone proficient to just show me the direct what i should looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what your looking for.  Below are a few examples of altering the default file types allowed by WordPress.  Keep in mind that some hosting companies will disallow some file types.

**Allow All File Types**

Add the following to wp-config.php to allow for any file type.

```
define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true );
```

---

**Allow or Disable Specific Types**

Add the following code into your theme's functions.php

```
function my_custom_mime_types( $mimes ) {

    // New allowed mime types.
    $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    $mimes['svgz'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    $mimes['doc'] = 'application/msword'; 

    // Optional. Remove a mime type.
    unset( $mimes['exe'] );

    return $mimes;
}

add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_custom_mime_types' );
```

---

**Resources**

[Allowed mime Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_allowed_mime_types)

[List of mime Types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)

---

**Plugins**

[WP Add Mime Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-add-mime-types/)

[Disable Mime Check](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-real-mime-check/)

Comment: note, I needed to remove the +xml from the end for it to actually work